# Windows accelerator for button, after doubled ampersand

Tags: windows, button, powerbuilder, accelerator

I'm using PowerBuilder (which I'm guessing isn't relevant to this problem, though I may be wrong).

I'm trying to set the text on a button to "Save && &New", which should read as "Save & New", with the "N" underlined.

It does, but I can't use the accelerator on the "N". (Pressing Alt-N just beeps.)

If I put the real accelerator before the doubled ampersand, for instance "&Save && New", it works fine when I press Alt-S.

I want it after the ampersand, on "New", because I have another button "&Save && Close" on the same window, and I want to distinguish those two buttons.

Is this a Windows bug? PowerBuilder? Any work-around, other than rewording, using the more wordy "and" instead of the ampersand, etc.?

Comment: It should not matter but have you got `N` as an accelerator on a menu?

Comment: OK, I created a tiny Windows Forms app to test this and it does not have the same problem, a button with the text "Save && &New" works by pressing Alt-N. So I guess it's a PowerBuilder issue. Anybody know about a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a PB bug: I have tested on my 11.5 PB (build 4843) by setting a button label to `some && &test`

- does not underlines the "test" first letter
- set the button accelerator to... "&" (!)

If I remove the doubled ampersand back to `some &test`, the accelerator is normally "t" (with or without using alt key).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a PB issue. PB uses the first ampersand it finds to identify the shortcut key. I don't know of any way to add an ampersand to button text without it screwing up your shortcut in some way.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be correct, except that it's OK to use an ampersand (doubled) as long as it is AFTER your accelerator key, e.g. "&Save && New". So I have to live within these limitations.